# Passing an unknown type between brackets

Tags: c#, delegates, functional-programming, unity-container, anonymous-types

How to pass an unknown type which will be defined in another class as a parameter in such an expression.
Don't know how to call the expression. and not sure why it can't remember the type between brackets and what's the solution.

```
.AddCallHandler<asp.CallHandlerType>
```

**The Code :**

```
 foreach (IAspect asp in Policy.Aspects)
 {
  //Type callHandlerType = asp.CallHandlerType;
  policy.AddMatchingRule(ruleLog)
    .AddCallHandler<asp.CallHandlerType>(new 
      ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
 }
```

It's said the type or namespace for "`asp`" doesn't exist.
Also I tried to define it earlier and pass it "`callHandlerType`", again a similar issue.

foreach asp the CallHandler type would be different, in one
it would be RestaurantCallHandler, in the other it could be MagicCallHandler.
Those were defined in aspects.

Interface's method definition :

```
public interface IAspect
{
   Type CallHandlerType { get; set; }
   // e.g it can be "MagicCallHandler : ICallHandler
}
```

Comment: Well where are you calling this method from? Could you make this a generic method?

Comment: @Jon Skeet Hi jon, yes I can. this is an AOP framework I'm writing for Unity. I'm posting the definition of the interface method. not professional on generics but always using them. If you changed it to generic form please post a sample line usage after calling. thanks

Comment: Ah, having read the question again, I think I see the problem. Okay... this can be done with reflection.

Comment: I've deleted my answer as with the newly-accepted one I don't think my one actually helps...

Comment: @Jon Skeet that was obvious that your answer would work in this and other similar situations and I appreciate that, I wanted to get your permission before changing the selected answer, the same time were sure you will be agree with me that Tuzo's answer is exactly direct answer to the question and there is no need for a hack, Anyway the hacks to such a problem are always useful and good to know, I appreciate that, thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if you don't know the type at compile you can use reflection to create a generic type at runtime.

However, in this case Unity provides non-generic method overloads (for most functionality) which accept argument(s) of type `System.Type` instead of generic type argument(s).  This allows you to specify types at runtime or to use unbound generic types.

In your case you can use this code to register your call handlers with no reflection required:

```
foreach (IAspect asp in Policy.Aspects)
{
    policy.AddMatchingRule(ruleLog)
      .AddCallHandler(asp.CallHandlerType, 
        new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
}
```

Comment: I was playing with the overloads, seems I missed this or intellisense as I remember it didn't show me any different overloads. It seems it should simply work. thanks.